# Reference request for a simple homological fact

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category,
and let $0 \to M \to N \to K \to 0$ be a short exact sequences of complexes with value in $\mathcal{A}$.

Then there is a long exact sequence in cohomology

$\dots \to H^n(M) \to H^n(N) \to H^n(K) \to H^{n+1}(M) \to \dots$

This is of course a simple homological fact, but I cannot find a direct proof of this in any book about homological algebra.

By a direct proof I mean a proof that does not use the Freyd–Mitchell embedding theorem.

The closest I found is Kashiwara and Schapira book "Sheaves on Manifolds", where the most important part of the proof is left as an exercise.

Does anyone know a book that has a direct proof of this fact in an Abelian category?

Comment: I think Kashiwara and Schapira's other book "Categories and Sheaves" has a complete proof.